# How do I convert a BigQuery row to JSON using the C# API?

Tags: c#, json, google-bigquery

I am pulling some data from a BigQuery table using the code below in C#

```
        BigQueryClient client = BigQueryClient.Create("<Project Name>");

        BigQueryTable table = client.GetTable("<Database>", "Students");

        string sql = $"select * FROM {table} where Marks='50'";
        BigQueryResults results = client.ExecuteQuery(sql);

        foreach (BigQueryRow row in results.GetRows())
        {

        }
```

I want to be able to either read the entire results variable into JSON or be able to get the JSON out of each row.

Of course, I could create  a class that models the table. And inside the `foreach` loop, I could just read each row into the class object. The class object I can try to serialize into JSON using a third party like "newton soft".

Something like :

```
class Student{
  int id;  // assume these are columns in the db
  string name;

}
```

My `foreach` would now look like:

```
    foreach (BigQueryRow row in results.GetRows())
    {
        Student s=new Student();
        s.id = Convert.ToString(row["id"]);
        s.name=  Convert.ToString(row["name"]);


        // something like  string x=x+ s.toJSON();  //using newton soft
    }
```

This way string x will have the JSON generated and appended for each row. 
Or is there a way I can just add each student to a collection or List and then get the JSON from the whole list?

This whole reading row by row and field by field seems tedious to me and there must be a simpler way I feel. Did not see any support from Google BigQuery for C# to directly convert to JSON. They did have something in Python.

If not then the list to JSON would be better but I am not sure if it supported.

**Update :**

https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-dotnet/blob/master/apis/Google.Cloud.BigQuery.V2/Google.Cloud.BigQuery.V2/BigQueryRow.cs

Looks like the Big Query Row class has a RawRow field which is of Type TableRow. And the class uses JSON references so , I am sure they have the data of the row in JSON format . How can I expose it to me ?

Comment: The query in your example will only return a single row, with a single field, containing the count.

Comment: @Nikki : sorry ..changed it !! now it returns fields and multiple rows!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This might be a little late but you can use:

```
var latestResult = _bigQueryClient.ExecuteQuery($"SELECT TO_JSON_STRING(t) FROM `{ProjectId}.{DatasetId}.{TableName}` as t", null
```

All columns will be serialized as json and placed in the first column on each row. You can then use something like Newtonsoft to parse each row easily.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same issue.
I am posting this solution which is not optimized for performance but very simple for multiple data types.
This allows you to deserialize anything (almost)

```
public class BQ
{
    private string projectId = "YOUR_PROJECT_ID";
 
    public BQ()
    {

    }       
    public List<T> Execute<T>(string sql)
    {
        var client = BigQueryClient.Create(projectId);

        List<T> result = new List<T>();
        try
        {
            string query = sql;
            BigQueryResults results = client.ExecuteQuery(query, parameters: null);
            List<string> fields = new List<string>();

            foreach (var col in results.Schema.Fields)
            {
                fields.Add(col.Name);
            }

            Dictionary<string, object> rowoDict;

            foreach (var row in results)
            {
                rowoDict = new Dictionary<string, object>();
                foreach (var col in fields)
                {
                    rowoDict.Add(col, row[col]);
                }
                string json = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(rowoDict);
                T o = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(json);
                result.Add(o);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
        }
        finally
        {
            client.Dispose();
            Console.WriteLine("Done.");
        }

        return result;

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this:

```
var res = Result. Getrows. Select(x=> new student(){id=x[`ID']}).
```

And then:

```
var js = json. Conver(res);
```

This way is much faster and clearer.

Comment: needed a way to avoid the explicit conversion (looks like it only got recently supported as in the first answer )  , but thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use ***Newtonsoft.Json***. First download by PackageManager Console the Nuget Package, [here](https://www.nuget.org/packages/newtonsoft.json/) you can get the command to do that.

After download you can use it as the following code:

```
List<Student> list = new List<Student>();
foreach (BigQueryRow row in results.GetRows())
{
    Student s=new Student();
    s.id = Convert.ToString(row["id"]);
    s.name=  Convert.ToString(row["name"]);
    list.Add(s);
}
var jsonResult = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(list);
```

I hope this can help you.

Comment: no ..i meant a direct way to parse the row into object

Answer (score 0):

Here is the complete solution for casting `BigQueryResults` or `GetQueryResultsResponse` or  `QueryResponse` data to Model/JSON format using C# reflection:

```
public List<T> GetBQAsModel<T>(string query) where T : class, new()
{
    var bqClient = GetBigqueryClient();
    var res = bqClient.ExecuteQuery(query, parameters: null);
    return GetModels<T>(res);
        
}

private List<T> GetModels<T>(BigQueryResults tableRows) where T : class, new()
{
    var lst = new List<T>();
    foreach (var item in tableRows)
    {
            
        var lstColumns = new T().GetType().GetProperties(BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic).ToList();
        var newObject = new T();
        for (var i = 0; i < item.RawRow.F.Count; i++)
        {
            var name = item.Schema.Fields[i].Name;
            PropertyInfo prop = lstColumns.FirstOrDefault(a => a.Name.ToLower().Equals(name.ToLower()));
            if (prop == null)
            {
                continue;
            }
            var val = item.RawRow.F[i].V;
            prop.SetValue(newObject, Convert.ChangeType(val, prop.PropertyType), null);
        }
        lst.Add(newObject);
            
    }
    return lst;
}

private List<T> GetModels<T>(GetQueryResultsResponse getQueryResultsResponse) where T : class, new()
{
    var lst = new List<T>();
    foreach (var item in getQueryResultsResponse.Rows)
    {

        var lstColumns = new T().GetType().GetProperties(BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic).ToList();
        var newObject = new T();
        for (var i = 0; i < item.F.Count; i++)
        {
            var name = getQueryResultsResponse.Schema.Fields[i].Name;
            PropertyInfo prop = lstColumns.FirstOrDefault(a => a.Name.ToLower().Equals(name.ToLower()));
            if (prop == null)
            {
                continue;
            }
            var val = item.F[i].V;
            prop.SetValue(newObject, Convert.ChangeType(val, prop.PropertyType), null);
        }
        lst.Add(newObject);

    }
    return lst;
}

private List<T> GetModels<T>(QueryResponse queryResponse) where T : class, new()
{
    var lst = new List<T>();
    foreach (var item in queryResponse.Rows)
    {

        var lstColumns = new T().GetType().GetProperties(BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic).ToList();
        var newObject = new T();
        for (var i = 0; i < item.F.Count; i++)
        {
            var name = queryResponse.Schema.Fields[i].Name;
            PropertyInfo prop = lstColumns.FirstOrDefault(a => a.Name.ToLower().Equals(name.ToLower()));
            if (prop == null)
            {
                continue;
            }
            var val = item.F[i].V;
            prop.SetValue(newObject, Convert.ChangeType(val, prop.PropertyType), null);
        }
        lst.Add(newObject);

    }
    return lst;
}
```