# Get column names of sql query when using bigquery API in c#

Tags: c#, google-bigquery

How can I print all the column names?
`Console.WriteLine(row.RawRow.ETag);` does not work it prints blank lines

This is my code so far

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<string> rows = new List<string>();
        string projectId = "project-id 123";
        var client = BigQueryClient.Create(projectId);
        string sql = @"SELECT * FROM table";
        var res = client.ExecuteQuery(sql, parameters: null);

        foreach (var row in res)
            Console.WriteLine(row["id"])
            //rows.Add(row["id"])
    }
```

Comment: Can you check the debugger within the foreach loop?

Comment: i found solution thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the examples has your answer

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42566229/how-do-i-convert-a-bigquery-row-to-json-using-the-c-sharp-api)

```
public List<T> Execute<T>(string sql)
{
    var client = BigQueryClient.Create(projectId);

    List<T> result = new List<T>();
    try
    {
        string query = sql;
        BigQueryResults results = client.ExecuteQuery(query, parameters: null);
        List<string> fields = new List<string>();

        foreach (var col in results.Schema.Fields)
        {
            fields.Add(col.Name);
        }
```